# How to write merge cell and unmerge cell together on one single line of the excell sheet

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet

If any one knows the solution of this problem please reply

```
use strict
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $Workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('cw.xls');
my $Worksheet1 = $Workbook->add_worksheet('MRD');

# Here $Groups[0] is unmerged cell

$Worksheet1->write(10,0, **$Groups[0]**,$Bg_Color);
my $i=1;    
foreach my $Grp(@Groups){
    my $Cell_Position = "$A2Z_Array[$i]10:$A2Z_Array[$i+1]10";
    $Worksheet1->merge_range($Cell_Position,**$Grp**,$Bg_Color_1);
    # Here $Grp is merged cell
    $i+=2;
}
```

Comment: can you show the piece of code, what you have done so far.

Comment: I have no idea what this code does without context. What type is `$Worksheet1`? How are you interfacing to Excel?

Comment: a more explanatory question title would be helpful to SO users too! looks like the poster is using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel - http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are using the Perl module [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm).

There isn't enough context in your question to figure out what is wrong but you could start by looking at the [merged cells examples](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Examples.pm#Example%3a_merge4.pl) in the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel docs.